# How do you draw a highlighted/selected bitmap on Windows?

Tags: c, winapi

I'm writing a program using the standard Win32 API.  When a user selects a picture in my program, I want to draw the bitmap so that it appears highlighted/selected.  Using the standard Windows metaphor, this means drawing a version of the bitmap that's been dithered with the system highlight color (I'm not sure that "dithered" is the technically correct term, but see my example below).  I've tried several ways to accomplish this with BitBlt and similar functions, but I can't seem to figure out the exact steps that I need.  If there's a standard Win32 function that handles this, I haven't been able to find it.  Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

An unselected image should look like this:

[image: Unselected image]

A selected image should look like this:

[image: Selected image]

Comment: I'd suggest not dithering and instead change the background color or draw an outline border. For example, when you highlight an item on the desktop, the icon itself doesn't change, but the background changes color. The benefit of this approach is that the user can still see the original picture clearly. Also, some images may be hard to tell apart from a dithered version, especially if the original is similar to the selection color. Using color *outside* the image avoids this issue.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely agree with your philosophy in general, but my goal is to mimic the image selection used by the Chrome web browser as closely as possible, and that's what it does.

Comment: Selecting items in a list vs content (not clear from qu which applies in your case) can require different UI: items in a list typically have plenty of space around them, so if they are inverted, some inverted border will show also. Content is trickier; images don't have a border space, so that's why text editors use the color-changing approach. So if you are actually highlighting images as part of and alongside textual content, then this is the appropriate thing to do, consistent with Chrome. But if these are images in a list, this is a different situation than what Chrome is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not figure out how to do this directly (e.g. with BitBlt and friends), but the image list object will do it for you:

```
HBITMAP hBitmapImage = ...; // cookie monster
HBITMAP hBitmapMask = ...; // all black
HIMAGELIST hImageList = ImageList_Create(width, height, ILC_COLOR32 | ILC_MASK, 1, 0);
ImageList_Add(hImageList, hBitmapImage, hBitmapMask);
ImageList_Draw(hImageList, 0, hDC, x, y, ILD_SELECTED);
```

Result (original on left, selected on right):

[image: Result]

Comment: I find using an all white mask to look even better in my code.  You can combine this with a highlight border to be even more obvious to your users.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the GDI [AlphaBlend()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183351(v=vs.85).aspx) should do the job; create a small solid bitmap using the highlight color, use AlphaBlend to overlay it on the original bitmap, using  BLENDFUNCTION.SourceConstantAlpha field to specify the transparency.

Comment: This is what I tried originally but the result was ugly; I think you need to premultiply the source image first.  I was too lazy to take it the extra step and ImageList already does it for you in a manner consistent with the system.  Of course if you want different affects (color, alpha, etc) you'll have to do the whole thing yourself.

Answer (score 0):

So how exactly you would like to have it highlighted? It might be a frame around the image, in which case you just need to `FrameRect` around. Or you might want to `PatBlt` the picture. Or check this article for another idea with sample code: [Glow and Shadow Effects using Windows GDI](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/Glow_and_Shadow_effects.aspx).

Comment: I want to draw the image dithered with the system highlight color, as I mentioned in my question.  I updated my question to include an example of the effect I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to invert your image to show selection using one of the Invert operations. For example to invert what is already present on an HDC pass the coordinates of the area to invert:

```
BitBlt(HDc, XPos, YPos, Width, Height, NULL, 0, 0, DSTINVERT);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really the effect I'm going for.  I edited my question to include an example.